# What are compiler flags for?Why won't my code compile?

Tags: c, ubuntu, compilation

I wrote a code in C in Ubuntu which checks for balanced brackets in the input given.I compiled it using gcc compiler and I am getting the correct output.This is actually a part of an online course and they are asking me to use the compiler flag

```
gcc -pipe -O2 -std=c11 filename -lm
```

I don't think I understand what I am supposed to do so I tried compiling using this flag and my code is not compiling. My question is if my code compiles when I do

```
gcc filename.c
```

why isn't it compiling when I do

```
gcc -pipe -O2 -std=c11 filename -lm
```

The error message I am getting is :

```
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-std=c11’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
```

Comment: Are you writing `flag` in front of `gcc`? Remove it. It's just plain wrong.

Comment: I did that by mistake.

Comment: Well, it's impossible to say why your code does not compile without code and error messages.

Comment: The reason has probably something to do with `c11` but if you do not provide more info it's impossible to say.

Comment: `-pipe` just avoids using files for temporary storage - is that required for local use, or for compilation by some online tool? It might make sense if they don't want their server cluttered with temporary files. All these options are [documented](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC)

Comment: Start taking the flags out one by one.  When you find the offending flag, read the documentation and figure out what it's failing on.  Also, you name your file `filename.C`, don't forget that unix (Ubuntu) is case-sensitive and will balk if you use `filename.c`.

Comment: Try deleting the `<>`. I guess it is only meant to mean "insert your own file name here". I .e. replace `<filename>` with `filename.C`.

Comment: If the file is `filename.C`, there's a possibility that the file contains C++ code rather than C code — or that GCC assumes it contains C++ code when it is actually C code — and that it doesn't like what it sees because it is the other language.  File names on Ubuntu are case-sensitive: `filename.c` and `filename.C` are different files, and normally represent code in different languages (lower-case `c` for C code; upper-case `C` for C++ code).  (See the GCC documentation for [Overall options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options).

Comment: Your question should include the exact text of the error message you get when you try to compile with `gcc -pipe -O2 -std=c11 <filename> -lm` or other explanation of what you mean by “my code is not compiling”.

Comment: As I said. Include the error message and stop forcing people to guess what's wrong.

Comment: I am getting a warning which says -std=c11 valid for C/obj C but not for C++

Comment: Type the command `which gcc` and post the output

Comment: Also, edit the question and add the *complete and exact* error message

Comment: output: /usr/bin/gcc

Comment: yes please wait

Comment: That's not the error message you mentioned earlier?

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 May 20 21:38 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-7

Comment: it changed after I changed the filename from C to c because someone said C is for C++

Comment: Please don't alter your question after you get answers. That invalidates old answers. If you have a new problem, post a new question, but SO is not for changing your question iteratively until your code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the file ending. A capital C is interpreted as a C++ file. The solution is to just rename the file like this:

```
mv filename.C filename.c
```

> My question is if my code compiles when I do `gcc filename.C` why isn't it compiling when I do `gcc -pipe -O2 -std=c11 <filename> -lm`

See above. But there are some situations where it would not solve everything. While C11 gives some extensions to previous versions, it's not 100% backwards compatible.

Comment: Yes I changed it.

Comment: I fixed it.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`-std=c11` is a correct option 
however you need at least `gcc 4.7` or higher to have this option

Answer (score -1):

By "<filename>" they mean to substitute in the name of the file you want to compile. Including the literal string "<filename>" will not work.